# Plotting timeline graph

Tags: pandas

https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0Slf.png

How do I plot the Date(x-axis) against the Target(y-axis)(the number of occurrences in that date? I want the 'Date' to be like a timeline kind of graph which has like 2020-01 , 2020-02 and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should do:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index,format = '%d/%m/%Y')
fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,6))
ax.plot(df.index.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),df['target'],'o') 
# If you don't want day, just put '%Y-%m'
# Rotate xticks
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKCGU.png Thanks, i got this now. How do i remove the black patches and pull the graph wider? Sorry new to this

Comment: I edited my answer. If you like the solution, accept it.